# Write the definition of a function, isReverse

Tags: c

Write the definition of a function,  isReverse , whose first two parameters are arrays of integers of equal size, and whose third parameter is an integer indicating the size of each array. The function returns true if and only if one array is the reverse of the other. ("Reverse" here means same elements but in reverse order.)

```
int isReverse(int array1[], int array2[], int size)
{ 
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(array1[i] == array2[size-1])
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

i keep getting an error. whats wrong with it.

Comment: You might want to share the error you are getting. Other that that, you realize that for loop is useless?

Comment: *Logic error?* You return after one iteration of your for-loop regardless.

Comment: WHAT error!? We're not psychic...

Comment: The return value of your function is not correct in certain cases.

Comment: Also, you're only checking one element of the second array: `array2[size-1]`

Comment: what if i set size to j and j-- it?

Comment: Add an additional RETURN as the last statement of your function.  That deals with `size <= 0`.  Your algorithm will still be wrong, but it will clear up that one error message.

Comment: @bhargavrao the entire post is closeworthy, no mcve

Answer (score 4):

When you `return` from  within any block in the function the function execution ends there, so in your case you are returning from function even when the first elements of the arrays are matching which is not correct, you should check whole array and then return from the function in the end, check the code below:

```
int isReverse(int array1[], int array2[], int size)
{ 
    int i,status=1;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++) //Size is the length of the array? if yes than you need -1 from it.
    {
        if(array1[i] == array2[size])
        {
            status=0;
            --size;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Moreover, `size-1` does not change the value of the variable size itself hence `size` will remain same throughout the loop, use `--size` this will decrement the value of actual variable hence decrementing it by one every time.

Comment: @ErgoProxy C has had a type named `bool` for 12 years. Just `#include <stdbool.h>` and it's right there.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is wrong because you are checking only 1 value from each array, not all of them. What you want to do is something like this.

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(!(array1[i] == array2[size-i-1])) 
       return 0;
}
return 1;
```

Basically you go through the array one by one, if any of the values are not the same as the appropriate value on the other array, it is not a reverse, so we return 0. If we get out of the for loop without going through the `if`, it means they are reverses so we return 1.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "size" never changes, so you're always checking elements of array1 against the last element of array2.

Since this sounds like a homework problem, I'll let you see if you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

```
    int isReverse(int array1[], int array2[], int SIZE)
    {
    for( int counter = 0; counter <= SIZE/2; counter++ )
    if(array1[counter] != array2[SIZE-counter] || array2[counter] != array1[SIZE-counter])
        return 1;
    return 0;
    }
```

You are just comparing the value at index i with a constant SIZE-1. Instead you want to compare the value at i with the comparison array's size-i. So each time the counter increments it compares with the opposite array's size-i. And you only have to do this for half of the array.

Comment: any specific reason for loop unrolling by 2? apart from performance, maybe?

Comment: I was thinking because only half need to be compared so this would minimize the work.

Comment: You are actually comparing entire array.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int isReverse(int array1[], int array2[], int size)
  {
      int flag = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
      if(array1[i] != array2[size-1]){
          flag = 1;
          break;
      }
      return flag;
      }
  }
```

In the code you have kept the return statement inside the loop... keep the return statement outside the loop and try

Answer (score 0):

```
int isReverse(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
int i = 0;
while (i<n)
{
if (a[i] != b[n-i-1]) {return 0; break;}
else i++;
}
return 1;
}
```

anw this was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isReverse(int array1[], int array2[],int size)
{
    int i=0;
    for (int k=0;k<size;k++){
        if (array1[k]==array2[size-k-1]){
           i++;
        }
    }
    if (i==size){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```